# Show message when web service is down

Tags: asp.net

How to show the custom message when the web service which is use in web application is down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `app_offline.htm` file on the root, that is the file that show the custom message

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke the web service, if it's down, use the 'CustomErrors' attribute in the web.config to go to your custom error page. You can tailor it to display different messages based on error code.

```
<error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
```

Comment: In custom error,what shoul i write for customerror mode & defaultredirect. For call web errror message.